# QGIS - repeat the function $area on multiple layers

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I, I have 15 layers on which I want to do exactly the same operation add columns and calculate the area (--> $area)
I looked online and found some hints with batch processing tools, BUT I've got errors messages with the Python advanced field calculator and errors with batch processing tools... can someone helps me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use pyqgis like this:

```
newfieldname = 'area'
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values(): #For each layer added to the map
    prov = layer.dataProvider()
    prov.addAttributes([QgsField(name=newfieldname, type=QVariant.Double)]) #Add an area field of type Double
    layer.updateFields()
    attributemap = {} #A dictionary to store feature id, new fieldindex, area
    fieldindex = layer.fields().indexFromName(newfieldname)
    for f in layer.getFeatures(): #For each feature add values to the dictionary
        attributemap[f.id()]={fieldindex:f.geometry().area()}
    prov.changeAttributeValues(attributemap) #Update all features
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there, sorry I try to redo the code now on my file but it says that there is something wrong with "prov=layer.dataProvider()" and brings the message "expected an intended block"...

Comment: Google the error. You need to indentate it. Add four spaces before it

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for being so dummie :D